# How can I simplify my R-code to make it shorter?

Tags: r, simplify

I'm analyzing data from a vacation home and I have this very long piece of code when I was trying to calculate prices for each apartment for each year and season. It works, but it is awfully long. I'm still a beginner in R and I would love to know also so I can learn from this.
This is my code:

```
ue <- ue %>% 
  mutate(price_night = case_when(
    ost > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('180'),
    ost > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('160'),
    ost > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('140'),
    west > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('180'),
    west > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('160'),
    west > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('140'),
    sued > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('100'),
    sued > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('80'),
    sued > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('60'),
    ost.west > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('360'),
    ost.west > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('320'),
    ost.west > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('280'),
    sued.ost > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('280'),
    sued.ost > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('240'),
    sued.ost > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('200'),
    sued.west > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('280'),
    sued.west > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('240'),
    sued.west > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('200'),
    gesamtes_haus > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('460'),
    gesamtes_haus > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('400'),
    gesamtes_haus > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2018 ~ as.numeric('340'),ost > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('240'),
    ost > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('210'),
    ost > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('170'),
    west > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('240'),
    west > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('210'),
    west > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('170'),
    sued > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('120'),
    sued > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('100'),
    sued > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('80'),
    ost.west > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('480'),
    ost.west > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('420'),
    ost.west > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('340'),
    sued.ost > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('360'),
    sued.ost > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('310'),
    sued.ost > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('250'),
    sued.west > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('360'),
    sued.west > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('310'),
    sued.west > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('250'),
    gesamtes_haus > 0 & hochsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('600'),
    gesamtes_haus > 0 & mittelsaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('520'),
    gesamtes_haus > 0 & nebensaison > 0 & year == 2022 ~ as.numeric('420'),
    TRUE ~ as.numeric('0')))
```

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e. `dput(head(ue, 20))`

Comment: Your statement `~as.numeric('180')` can be simplified as `~180`, here the code is passing a string `'180'` and then converting to numeric.

Comment: Usually something like this could be done with a look-up table and a join, but all the `> 0`s make that strange. Without seeing sample data and knowing more context it's hard to know how important the order of these conditions are, why you are using `> 0` instead of an `==` check for the season and direction variables (and if it could be easily converted to `==`), etc. Or perhaps the season and direction variables could be combined into 2 columns, `saison` and `richtung`--if necessary in order of precedence for your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch your strategy from storing all the identities of `price_night` into a file instead of code.  There are enough conditions here to warrant a different strategy.

It's generally a good idea to store data in files instead of code.  It's easier to edit a file than code. You can display the table stored in the file easier than showing collaborators the code.  These are just two reasons.

The way I'd accomplish it in your case:

- store the various conditions as new columns in your data frame.  For example, a column `west_gt_0 = west > 0`.
- create a .csv file in Excel with those same column names and the value of `price_night` that they define.  The columns will be like `west_gt_0, nebensaison_gt_0, ..., year, price_night`
- Read this table into code and join it to your data frame.
- Share the table with the definitions with your collaborators and/or display in your notebook so people can see it and possibly spot any errors or mistakes

```
price_def <- read_csv("price_night.csv")
ue <- left_join(
  ue, 
  price_def, 
  by = names(price_def) %>% setdiff("price_night")
)
```

Comment: Hey everyone, thank you for your thoughts on this.